# How to access the upper corner in Foliana Heights

Tags: tinykin

The top part of the Greenhouse level takes place on beams of the ceiling.  However, the corner section is blocked off by walls.  The only place I've seen to potentially access it is covered in spiky plants, and I can't build a tower tall enough to float over because of the roof.  There's collectibles over there, though, so I'm sure there has to be a way to get over there.